# Clear field with touchstart/touchend and timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I had the following which worked fine in browser for what I needed:

```
var timer;
$('.played').on({
    'focus': function () {
        $(this).val(function (i, v) {
            return (+v || 0) + 1;
        }).blur();
    },
    'mousedown': function () {
        var $el = $(this);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $el.val('');
        }, 5000);
    },
    'mouseup': function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
});
```

However when I came to use it on my iPad, it wouldn't clear the fields on hold, I've since found out that's to do with touchstart/touchend, so I've now got the following http://jsfiddle.net/e1kb6esm/12/

Problem is now that although it kind of works, I have to slide my finger away from the field I've focused on, otherwise it picks up another touch after resetting, so instead of clearing the field, it reverts to 1.

Anyone got any ideas?